# What is SDL_Surface?

Tags: c++, sdl

I am following a tutorial by lazyfoo http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/index2.php
and when drawing to the screen a 'surface is used. What is it, is it the similar to SDL_Texture? Is it to do with buffers?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading documentation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This question is easily answered by looking at the documentation.

### [`SDL_Texture`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Texture)

---

SDL_Texture contains an efficient / optimized representation of the pixel data. `SDL_Texture` was introduced in SDL2.0 and enables hardware rendering. The way to render a `SDL_Texture` is

```
void SDL_RenderPresent
(
    SDL_Renderer* renderer
)
```

You should try to use only `SDL_Texture` as they are optimized for rendering, contrary to `SDL_Surface`

### **[`SDL_Surface`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface)**

---

An SDL_Surface is basically a struct that contains all the raw pixel data along with some meta-information like size and pixel format. Since `SDL_Surface` is just the raw pixel data, it is not optimized in any way and should be avoided when rendering.

Some parts of SDL2.0 still uses `SDL_Texture` ( like image loading or text rendering )

Luckily, you can simply convert an `SDL_Surface` to `SDL_Texture` using

```
SDL_Texture* SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface
(
    SDL_Renderer* renderer,
    SDL_Surface*  surface
)
```

---

For more information about SDL2 and how to use it to make games, you can check out my [blog.](http://headerphile.com/)

Comment: Thanks you, can I use SDL_Texture instead if I feel more comfortable with it?

Comment: @user3731338 You should try to always use `SDL_Texture` as `SDL_Surface` isn't optimized. See my updated answer.