# SDL_UpdateTexture ARGB much faster than RGBA

Tags: c, sdl-2, rgba, argb

I was trying to use `SDL_UpdateTexture` to create a texture from an allocated buffer of pixels, and I was surprised that it wasn't even rendering at 60fps (with the main culprit being `SDL_UpdateTexture`):

```c
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

static double time_in_ms(void) {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_sec * 1000.0 + tv.tv_usec / 1000.0;
}

int main(void) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Pixel formats" , 0, 0, 1920, 1080, 0);
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    double last_frame = time_in_ms();
    while (1) {
        int width, height;
        SDL_Event e;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        SDL_GetWindowSize(window, &width, &height);
        SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, width, height);
        Uint32 *pixels = malloc(width * height * sizeof(*pixels));
        /* fill buffer with blue pixels */
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            Uint32 *row = pixels + y * width;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                row[x] = 0x0000FFFF;
            }
        }

        double update_begin = time_in_ms();
        SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, pixels, width * sizeof(*pixels));
        double update_end = time_in_ms();
        SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(texture, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
        free(pixels);
        double this_frame = time_in_ms();
        printf("frame took %fms\n", this_frame - last_frame);
        printf(" - update texture: %fms\n", update_end - update_begin);
        last_frame = this_frame;
    }

}
```

But, if I just change `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888` to `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888` (and update `0x0000FFFF` to `0xFF0000FF`), all of a sudden, `SDL_UpdateTexture` goes down from taking ~15ms per frame to ~1ms. This happens regardless of whether `renderer` is an accelerated or software renderer. This seems very strange to me, since even if `SDL_Texture`s  are internally ARGB, it takes far less than 15ms to convert from RGBA to ARGB:

```c
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    Uint32 *row = pixels + y * width;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        Uint32 a = row[x] & 0xFF;
        row[x] >>= 8;
        row[x] |= a << 24;
    }
}
```

Why might it be that `SDL_UpdateTexture` is so much faster with ARGB than RGBA (and does this vary across platforms)?

(`SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB888` is also quite fast (~2ms), but not as fast as ARGB)

Comment: What texture formats (via `SDL_GetRendererInfo()`) does your renderer support?  See the loop near the top of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33312056/44729).

Comment: @genpfault It doesn't appear there, so I guess that explains it. But it still doesn't really make sense that it should take *that long* to convert it to ARGB (not to mention the fact that RGB isn't nearly as slow).

Comment: If I've traced things through right it's probably bottoming out in `SDL_Blit_RGBA8888_ARGB8888_Scale()` (double-check with your debugger).  At a minimum that'll be a (fancy) copy, possibly with an allocation thrown in.  As opposed to your in-place conversion loop.

Comment: @LeoTenenbaum there is no specialised RGBA8->ARGB8 blitter in SDL, so `SDL_ConvertPixels` (called by update with "wrong" format) falls back to slow possible generic conversion. See https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/200f23b4f8d2/src/video/SDL_blit_N.c#l3336 and implementation of `BlitNtoNCopyAlpha` in the same file. There probably are better ways to do this in case of so large texture, ecpecially if you have multiple CPU cores.

Comment: @genpfault spot on about in-place though, even with simple loop in question writing to new array is pretty much the same perf as `SDL_ConvertPixels` (may be better with `-O3`, but SDL is not very likely to be compiled with that).