# How to draw a grid of pixels fast with sdl2?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have the following function which draws a grid of pixels on the window, I'm using sdl.

The problem is that is very slow! It makes my program to run at 10fps, so I think Im must be doing something wrong.

This is the code I'm using

```
void rayTracing(SDL &sdl) {
  int nx = 1440;
  int ny = 810;

  for (int x = 0; x < nx; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < ny; y++) {
      float r = float(x) / float(nx);
      float g = float(y) / float(ny);
      float b = 0.2;
      int ir = int(255.99 * r);
      int ig = int(255.99 * g);
      int ib = int(255.99 * b);

      SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(sdl.renderer.get(), ir, ig, ib, 255);
      SDL_RenderDrawPoint(sdl.renderer.get(), x, ny - y);
    }
  }

  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(sdl.renderer.get(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Maybe the problem is the way I use SDL_RenderDrawPoint?

Comment: Which version of SDL are you using?  If you can, upgrade to one of the recent ones that supports SDL_Renderer batching (2.0.10+?) & force-enable it via the `SDL_HINT_RENDER_BATCHING` hint.  Otherwise, group your points by color & use `SDL_RenderDrawPoints()`.  Or, since everything is just in a grid, load your pixels into a SDL_Texture & draw that.

Comment: I'll try SDL_HINT_RENDER_BATCHING, and SDL_RenderDrawPoints doesn't works on this case for me.

How should I do it with SDL_Texture in a performant way?

Comment: [Like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33312056/44729).

Comment: It would be much faster if implemented with OpenGL & shaders.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat do you know a tutorial for that?

Comment: https://learnopengl.com/ is a good tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet may be to create a separate render texture that you can access directly through a pointer. You make your changes and when you are done, you call an SDL texture update once and it will transfer your in-memory texture to the display.

This is how you create the SDL texture

```
theTexture = SDL_CreateTexture( theRenderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, nx, ny );
```

You would then also create an in-memory buffer to draw to

```
uint32_t *textureBuffer = new uint32_t[ nx * ny ];
```

At this point, drawing a pixel really just comes down to writing the respective RGB8888 color value to the textureBuffer array, kind of like this

```
textureBuffer[(yPos*nx) + xPos] = 0xFF000000 | (ir<<16) | (ib<<8) | ig;
```

After drawing to it, you can then update the entire texture in one swoop like this

```
SDL_UpdateTexture( theTexture , NULL, textureBuffer, nx * sizeof (uint32_t));
```

Comment: Yes, it does, as long as each of the platforms supports the pixel format you are using. If you don't need full ARGB8888, you can also use RGB888, or RGB565, etc.
ARGB8888 is my preference for most platforms because it makes every pixel a 32-bit entry, allowing you to optimize your drawing loops and indexing accordingly. With a 24-bit format, you always run into alignment issues, etc, because no native 24-bit data type exists in C/C++.

Comment: thank you, it works well. one thing is that my image now is upside down

how I can change this to flip it?

textureBuffer[(yPos*nx) + xPos) = 0xFF000000 | (ir<<16) | (ib<<8) | ig;

Comment: Hmmh, that is strange. It should not be upside down—unless you loaded a BMP file into the buffer, which is inherently stored upside down.

Comment: yeah, its because of how I was rendering the raytracer, now I just reverse the y and its fine

Comment: I followed this solution, I am also making a ray tracer. With a larger width and height, the program closes and I get a `segmentation fault: 11`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Segmentation faults are typically an indicator that you are writing outside your allocated buffer. Make sure your pointers and lengths are correct.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by removing the malloc call I was using to create the array and instead created it using `uint32_t textureBuffer[size]`