# SDL Stops rendering to window after renderer is destroyed/created when resizing window

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I have made a windows program where I display my output by drawing pixels to a window with SDL.
I started from a tutorial, and made a program with two windows, and everything worked fine.
But then I noticed if I only opened one window, and resized it, the rendering stopped working.

I have reduced my code to minimal working example, and tried to remove all other fault sources like deleting pointers, and resizing the texture.

The problem is in resizeWindow(), when I destroy and recreate _renderer it stops rendering to the window (last rendered image remains visible).

If I add the out-commented lines (which creates a second window) resizing works fine again, which is very weird to me. But that might not be important to solving the bug.
Here is the full code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class LocalWindow{
public:
  LocalWindow(){}
  SDL_Window* _window = NULL;
  SDL_Renderer* _renderer = NULL;
  SDL_Texture* _texture = NULL;
  uint8_t* _pixels1;
  uint8_t* _pixels2;
  int displayPixels = 1;
  int windowHeight = 400;
  int windowWidth = 600;
  Uint32 windowId;

  void open(){
    _window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Graphics", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, windowWidth, windowHeight, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    windowId = SDL_GetWindowID(_window);
    _renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(_window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize(_renderer, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    _texture = SDL_CreateTexture(_renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA32, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, windowWidth, windowHeight);

    _pixels1 = new uint8_t[windowWidth * windowHeight * 4];
    for(int i=0; i<windowWidth*windowHeight; i++){
      _pixels1[i*4] = 0x00;
      _pixels1[i*4+1] = 0x00;
      _pixels1[i*4+2] = 0x00;
      _pixels1[i*4+3] = 0x00;
    }
    _pixels2 = new uint8_t[windowWidth * windowHeight * 4];
    for(int i=0; i<windowWidth*windowHeight; i++){
      _pixels2[i*4] = 0x33;
      _pixels2[i*4+1] = 0x33;
      _pixels2[i*4+2] = 0x33;
      _pixels2[i*4+3] = 0x33;
    }
  }

  virtual void resizeWindow(int windowHeight, int windowWidth){
    SDL_DestroyTexture(_texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(_renderer);
    _renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(_window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize(_renderer, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    _texture = SDL_CreateTexture(_renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA32, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, this->windowWidth, this->windowHeight);
  }

  virtual void prepareRender(){
    int texture_pitch = 0;
    void* texture_pixels = NULL;
    SDL_LockTexture(_texture, NULL, &texture_pixels, &texture_pitch);
    if(displayPixels == 1)
      memcpy(texture_pixels, _pixels1, texture_pitch * windowHeight);
    else
      memcpy(texture_pixels, _pixels2, texture_pitch * windowHeight);
    displayPixels = 3 - displayPixels;
    SDL_UnlockTexture(_texture);
    SDL_RenderCopy(_renderer, _texture, NULL, NULL);

    string err = SDL_GetError();
    if(err.length() > 0)
      cout << err << endl;
  }

  virtual void render(){
    SDL_RenderPresent(_renderer);
  }
};

int main( int argc, char* args2[] )
{
  LocalWindow mapWindow;
  mapWindow.open();
  //SDL_Window* _window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Graphics2", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 40, 40, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
  //SDL_CreateRenderer(_window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

  auto startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  auto currentTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  while(true){
    currentTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    if(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(currentTime - startTime).count() > 500){
      mapWindow.prepareRender();
      mapWindow.render();
      startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }
    SDL_Event e;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
      if(e.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && (int)e.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED && e.window.windowID == mapWindow.windowId)
          mapWindow.resizeWindow(e.window.data2, e.window.data1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note that my original program looked very different, so no need pointing out other dumb things I have done, other then what ever I have done to break the renderer :)

Why does my renderer stop working when I resize my window?

Comment: Why are you recreating the renderer in the first place?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat
This was the way I found to draw raw pixels to a window. I dont know alot about SDL or graphics, so if there is a way to do it without a renderer that could solve my problem.

Comment: There's also `SDL_GetWindowSurface()` if you just want raw pixels. But even you do this with a renderer, why recreate it? Just create it once?

Comment: I thought I needed to recreate the renderer since I recreate the texture and change the size of both of them.
But I will test these two things you have mentioned.

Comment: So I tried to just not delete and recreate the renderer, and that worked!
If someone can give me insight into why recreating the renderer makes the rendering stop I would be curious to know, but I think my problem is now solved.
Thanks @HolyBlackCat

I also tried the SDL_GetWindowSurface(), and copy my pixels to _surface->pixels. That did not work. Perhaps I need to replace SDL_RenderPresent with something, or check set/check the pixel format, but I did read that texture>surface, so I will not spend more time on it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170028/what-is-sdl-surface